# How to make django registration form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

I need to make a registration form in django able to set user group upon creation.

My users upon creation should be able to set groups upon creation.

Comment: You need to add more information. What libraries do you use for registration if any. What have you tried? This is too broad.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I got your question you have to create one field that refers to GROUP inside USER model. And that is what we call `ForeignKey()` field of `django.db.models`
And so your `models.py` may look something like this

```
models.py

from django.db import models

class Group(models.Model):
    group_id = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True, 
        editable=False,
    )
    group_name = models.CharField(
        "Group Name", 
        blank=False
    )
    ......    
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True, 
        editable=False,
    )
    user_name = models.CharField(
        "User Name", 
        blank=False
    )
    group = ForeignKey(Group, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    ......
```

And then set `views.py` and all required stuffs. For more follow [Model field reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/) and [Writing your first Django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) best place to learn whole framework step by step.